# Написал программу (тестовая задача) от потенциального работодателя. Как её отправить?

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, debian, jar

Java, Intellij IDEA

Написал программу.
На вход даются файлы: *.tsv, *.xml
На выходе получить *.txt вариант таблицы

Полтора дня писал программу.
Когда запускаю итоговый вариант в IDE через "Edit configuration...", всё замечательно компилируется и выдаётся тот самый заветный файл.тхт.

Но крайнее требование в ТЗ, чтобы программа выдавала файл посредством вызова команды в терминале типа:

```
java Name.class file.xml file.tsv result.txt
```

И вот тут я завис окончательно, потому что из директории ./out/../Name.class эта команда выдаёт

```
Could not find or load main class Name.class
```

Потеряв надежду (было много попыток и гугла ~10-15 минут), решил запилить jar файл и тупо отправить его HRу.

Но чего-то передумал и решил написать сюда.
Git я знаю на уровне
init, commit, status, add
т.е. только на уровне сохранить у себя.
Пытался

```
git add --all
```

но он оказывается не хочет добавлять папки (онли файлы)

```
fatal: CRLF будет заменен на LF в settings.xml.
```

Напишите пожалуйста:

1. Откуда (директория) всё-таки нужно запускать java Name.class... и что перед этим может нужно сделать в IDEA (экспортировать/импортировать/...)?
2. Каким путём отправить файл HRу (общались по почте)?

PS: ноутбук к нему не понесу
PPS: у меня стоит Debian

Comment: вам надо собрать артефакт, то есть получить Name.jar, а потом уже делать `java -jar Name.jar`

Comment: Lex Hobbit, огромное вам спасибо!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не обязательно собирать `jar` для запуска программы. По сути `jar` является лишь архивом, содержащим в себе все скомпилированные файлы (с расширением `.class`), а также файл манифеста, в котором помимо всего прочего указано, с какого класса начать запуск программы (в каком из классов имеется нужный метод `main`).

Как запустить `jar` уже описывали выше. А для того, чтобы запустить программу не из пакета, а ту, которая просто скомпилирована в виде файла `.class` необходима следующая команда:

```
java {ClassName} {arguments}
```

где ClassName - полный путь до класса, включая имя пакета, если он есть. Кроме того, скомпилированный файл, соответствующий указанному классу должен быть расположен в папке, соответствующей пакету:

- например, если есть файл `Test1.class` (с классом `Test1` без пакета) - строка запуска будет `java Test1` из той же папки;
- если есть файл `Test2.class` (соответственно с классом `Test2` и указанием пакета `org.sample`) - запуск будет осуществляться командой `java org.sample.Test2`, а файл `Test2.class` должен лежать в папке `org/sample` относительно места, откуда производится запуск.

Надеюсь, это будет полезно.

Answer (score 2):

Собираем артефакт!
Затем прописываем

```
java -jar Name.jar file.xml file.tsv res.txt
```

Огромное спасибо, Lex.

Comment: раз уж вы решили отправлять в таком виде, то есть программа будет запускаться из консоли, добавьте хоть грамотный парсинг аргументов и чтобы они как-то назывались + usage  проверку на количество аргументов и т.д. а по поводу как отправлять соберите все исходники и jar в архив и напишите маломальское сопроводительное письмо

Answer (score 1):

Если плохо знаеш Git, то можна закинуть проект на GitHub через Intellij  IDEA. Вот тут подробно расписано: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/how-to-add-an-intellij-project-to-github.html